# How to Syncing Offline MySQL db to online MySQL db

Tags: sync, php, phpmyadmin

I am developing a inventory management web application using php and mysql. This application will runs on server hosting and localhost. while any one server disconnect the internet at the time data will be land in local database and when active internet that data automatically synchronizing the remote database. is there way pls let me know.

thanks and advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are lots of ways to synchronize databases. I think you'll get more luck finding which one works best for you if you say a bit more about this: "while any one server disconnect the internet at the time data will be land in local database".

When your remote server disconnects from the internet, it won't be able to send data back to your localhost - so you'd be much better off looking into synchronising it every X hours (or every X days, or minutes, depending on what you need that database for).

One of the best ways to do this is by configuring cron on your server so that it automatically exports the database and then sends it back to your home computer - but exporting a database will lock it as the copy is made, so there are decision to make about how often you want to take a copy and how much of a performance hit the site can take while that happens.